# Unable to uninstall websphere mq, facing error 1713

Tags: ibm-mq

We have issue. As of our application requirement.we are going to migrate from the mq v7.0.1.8 to v7.5.0.7, on windows environment.

1. We are unable to uninstall MQ version 7.0.1.8,  while we trying uninstall from control panel or command mode we have facing error.

   Error is.

   ```
    "1713 IBM websphere mq cannot install one of its required product, contact your technical support group." System error 1605"
   ```
2. We have Given command to unistalling websphere mq from the server through command mode.

   ```
    Msiexec /i {product code} REMOVE= "ALL" installationname="installation0"
   ```
3. We have checked in MSI error logs :
   `C:\windows\installer\68009a4d.msi` is missing
4. can we know to how to restore this missing MSI file.

Is there any other way unistall the websphere mq from the machine.

5. the below path only i found this error(C:\windows\installer\68009a4d.msi` is missing)

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp,

we have tried to install the Microsoft ORCA utility on server we facing some JDK related error.
is there any another way to uninstall this old version from the server.

sorry for late reply,

this issue still in pending state.we haven't receive any update from user for this installation on machine.

Comment: It is probably easier to open a ticket with IBM.

Comment: Note for IBM MQ questions please just take it as [ibm-mq], this is monitored by people familiar with the product.  The [websphere] tag is for questions about the Websphere Application Server, and the [mq] tag is a very generic tag for questions that are not about any specific MQ product.

Comment: Also note that MQ v7.5 is going out of support in a few months on April 30 2018.  if you are going to upgrade from v7.0, your time and effort would be better spent on upgrading to v8.0 or v9.0 since these will be supported longer (IBM has not announced end of support for either, but gives at least 5 years, my guess on end of support is April 2020 for v8.0 and April 2022 for v9.0)

Comment: From what I can tell the Microsoft ORCA utility is a exe file and would have nothing to do with Java, can you please explain what type of JDK related error you receive, how you are attempting to run it, etc?

Comment: Any update praveen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a match for [APAR IC78398](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC78398)

> **Error description**
>
> While uninstalling the MQ client, it fails when removing the 32-bit
>   runtime (iwiUninstall32bitComponentsVista) with System Error 1605.The
>   MSI log shows the following:
>
> ```
> Action start 17:02:02: iwiUninstall32bitComponentsVista.
> MSI (s) (BC:B0) [17:02:02:793]: Warning: Local cached package
> 'C:\Windows\Installer\62870feb.msi' is missing.
> MSI (s) (BC:CC) [17:02:02:793]: Note: 1: 1713 2: IBM WebSphere
> MQ 3:  1605
> MSI (s) (BC:CC) [17:05:25:512]: Product: IBM WebSphere MQ --
> Error 1713.IBM WebSphere MQ cannot install one of its required
> products. Contact your technical support group
> System Error: 1605.
> ```

The APAR link above and the IBM Technote "[WebSphere MQ self help – Common install/uninstall issues for MQ Version 7 on Windows](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21654327)" under a section `4) Problem: Uninstallation of WebSphere MQ stops with the error 1605, and a warning similar to the following example is reported in the install or uninstall log:
Warning: Local cached package 'C:\Windows\Installer\468c9631.msi' is missing.` both provide a work around using a Microsoft utility as quoted below.

Note that the APAR shows the fix for the issue is in 7.0.1.8, but the Technote explains that if the original install was 7.0.1.7 or earlier that you will still have the problem even if it is later upgraded to 7.0.1.8 or later.

> **Local fix**
>
> Edit the cached MSI database file with Microsoft ORCA utility and put
>   an install condition of 0 (i.e, false) against the custom action we
>   don't want executed, in this case iwiUninstall32bitComponentsVista and
>   iwiUninstall64bitComponentsVista
>
> The information to download and set up ORCA utility is available at:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
>
> Steps are as follows:
>
> 1. Use Microsoft ORCA utility to open the cached WebSphere MQ Client MSI database file (which will be located at C:\Windows\Installer).You
>      can use Windows Explorer to open C:\Windows\Installer and switch to
>      detailed view. Then add "comments" column to the view, and the file we
>      need to open in ORCA GUI will show "WebSphere MQ Client MSI database"
>      or "WebSphere MQ MSI database" as the comment.
> 2. There will probably be three of these.  Open the largest one with ORCA and confirm that the "View"->"Summary Information ..." dialog
>      shows a "title" or "IBM WebSphere MQ for Windows, Version 7.0"
> 3. Select InstallExecuteSequence in the Tables section of ORCA.
> 4. Select iwiUninstall32bitComponentsVista from Action column.
> 5. The default value in Condition is : (REMOVE="ALL") and Installed and (VersionNT >= 600)
> 6. Remove the above line and replace it with a zero - "0".
> 7. Repeat steps 4, 5, and 6 but this time for the iwiUninstall64bitComponentsVista action, setting the condition on this
>      to zero - "0" - also.
> 8. Save the changes made to WebSphere MQ Client MSI database file.
> 9. Attempt to uninstall MQ client again from the system.